# Removing dynamic controls : Clear is working but not remove

Tags: c#, asp.net, postback, dynamic-controls, createchildcontrols

I faced a recent problem, where I was generating the dynamic control on the selection of drop down. When the selection changes, I have to generate another set of dynamic controls, removing the existing controls.

So I was doing following which is not working:

```
    private void ClearDynamicControls()
    {
        if (adapter != null)
        {
            //This has all the controls saved in some dictionary, key as control ID
            var controls = adapter.GetAllControls().Keys;
            Control mainControl = (PlaceHolder)this.Form.FindControl("MainContent");

            foreach (String controlName in controls)
            {
                Control controlToRemove = this.Form.FindControl("MainContent").FindControl(controlName);
                mainControl.Controls.Remove(controlToRemove);

            }
            var controls2 = mainControl.Controls;
            //clearing the controls in the dictionary
            adapter.ClearAllControls();
        }


    }
```

But the similar code with Clear() method is working fine. So what shall I do about it?

```
    private void ClearDynamicControls()
    {
        if (adapter != null)
        {
            //This has all the controls saved in some dictionary, key as control ID
            var controls = adapter.GetAllControls().Keys;
            Control mainControl = (PlaceHolder)this.Form.FindControl("MainContent");
            mainControl.Controls.Clear();


            //clearing the controls in the dictionary
            adapter.ClearAllControls();
        }


    }
```

By this code, all the controls(both dynamic and static) are removed. So what shall be done about it?

Please let me know if I am doing something wrong.

I am calling this method on dropdown selection change event firing. These controls are added to the table...

Comment: Are you sure that the foreach loop is executing?

Answer (score 1):

If you know your control's names you could use this:

```
foreach(Control control in Controls){
  if(control.Name == "yourControlName"){
    Controls.Remove(control);
  }
}
```

or if you want to remove all controls from a panel for example you could use:

```
foreach(Control control in panel.Controls){      
        panel.Controls.Remove(control);
    }
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: thanks for the reply, but the issue is I am adding dynamic as well static controls to the table, it is getting cleared via Clear() function, but not by remove function. I want to preserve the static controls, before next page load.

Comment: did you tried putting the dynamic controls on some container which host only the dynamic controls and then removing all of them?